# Grails Criteria multiple hasMany intersection

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I've been trying to query with multiple hasMany objects, such as:

```
def product = Product.createCriteria().list {
  createAlias("productAttributeValues", "pav")    

  and {    

    if (session.filters?.filter_instore) {
        and {
          eq("pav.attribute", Attribute.findByCode("instore"))
          eq("pav.valueDe", session.filters?.filter_instore?.toString())
        }
    }

    if (session.filters?.filter_promo) {
      and {
        eq("pav.attribute", Attribute.findByCode("promo"))
        eq("pav.valueDe", "1")
      }
    }
  }    
}
```

This doesn't seem to work, since I never get a result set, although I have test data that would match. It seems that the problem is that I'm querying twice with the same objects.

One possible solution would be to query the productAttributeValues seperately and then intersect with a "in"("myPavs", pavs) - but this seems to be inefficient to me.

Any thoughts?
Thanks.

Comment: is the `Product.productAttributeValues` a (hasMany) collection?

Comment: Yes, it is a hasMany collection.

Answer (score 1):

I would re-build your query so:

```
def products = Product.withCriteria{
  productAttributeValues{    
    or{
      if (session.filters?.filter_instore) {
        and {
          eq("attribute", Attribute.findByCode("instore"))
          eq("valueDe", session.filters?.filter_instore?.toString())
        }
      }

      if (session.filters?.filter_promo) {
        and {
          eq("attribute", Attribute.findByCode("promo"))
          eq("valueDe", "1")
       }
      }
    }
  }    
}
```

Comment: I suppose, this doesn't work since attribute and value is linked together and must therefore kept together. In your example, it's seperated. Am I wrong?

Comment: no, the default junction in criteria queries is `and`

Comment: I mean that attribute and its value (valueDe) is considered seperately. Take ProductAttributeValue1 with Attribute 'R' and Value 'Bla' and ProductAttributeValue2 with Attribute 'B' and Value 'Ble'. Your query seems to just consider all attribute R and B as well as Bla and Ble. This could result in querying other combinations, such as Attribute 'R' and Vlue Ble which may exist?

Comment: then you should combine the `and`-clauses with `or`-conjunction, see the update

Comment: Thanks, I'll check your solution. Meanwhile, I came up with the idea to list ProductAttributeValues according to the respective filters, groupBy productId and do the intersection via Groovy. Works like a charm.